# Laravel couldn't validate my correct form

Tags: laravel

in `Laravel` and my web application i have a simple form which i pasted below line:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{url('/addToContactUs')}}" method="POST">
    @csrf

    <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 control-label" for="name">Your Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" name="name" value="{{old('name')}}" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 control-label" for="email">Your Email</label>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" name="email" value="{{old('email')}}" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 control-label" for="enquiry">Your Enquiry</label>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-9">
            <textarea name="enquiry" rows="10" class="form-control">{{old('enquiry')}}</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

when i try to validate form fields, i get this error:

```
array:3 [▼
  1 => array:1 [▼
    0 => "The 1 field is required."
  ]
  3 => array:1 [▼
    0 => "The 3 field is required."
  ]
  5 => array:1 [▼
    0 => "The 5 field is required."
  ]
]
```

and when i try to log `$request` i have:

```
array:4 [▼
  "_token" => "W8xPG039mlT0WGs0kw9lWV0FivYxKSx4XHg6LPkQ"
  "name" => "this is my name"
  "email" => "hello@gmail.com"
  "enquiry" => "hello hello hello hello hello hello "
]
```

it seems all implementations are correct and i don't know why i get this error.

route for submitting this form:

```
Route::post('/addToContactUs', 'HomeController@addToContactUs');
```

and controller `action`:

```
public function addToContactUs(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make(
        $request->all(),
        [
            'name', 'required|string|min:5|max:191',
            'email', 'required|string|min:5|max:191|email',
            'enquiry', 'required|string|min:5',
        ]
    );
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        dd($validator->errors()->messages(),$request->all());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After seeing your full validation method again & again, I got the error here,  `'name', 'required…` it will be `'name' => 'required…`. Its just a typo,  so your code will be :

```
$validator = Validator::make(
        $request->all(),
        [
            'name' => 'required|string|min:5|max:191',
            'email' => 'required|string|min:5|max:191|email',
            'enquiry' => 'required|string|min:5',
        ]
    );
```